# Run Application Flow - Timeout value (Microsoft Power Automate)

Tags: power-automate-desktop

In the "Run Application" flow, there is a "Timeout" setting. Is this setting in seconds? Milliseconds? Something else? The information tooltip does not say in what format it is, nor does the [online documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/system#runapplicationbase).

[image: Run application flow dialog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stored in **seconds**.

I tested that by launching Visual Studio and it waits for the amount of seconds specified before it moves on.

[image]

Comment: Not sure who is the designer of the form, but it's clearly UX needs more improvement of what's the unit for the timeout! I was trying to find documentation and couldn't find any.